# out of memory exception android in android?

Tags: android

i am making an application and on the start of application i want to display a picture but i get this `out of memory exception`. i used a lot of shared Preferences in the code that is not yet executed. so this rises 2 questions -

is memory for shared Preferences allocated at the beginning itself ?

and is the memory for shared Preferences allocated in the apps heap memory ?

should i clear the shared preferences and use database instead . will that solve the problem ?

Comment: are you running it on emulator?

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/254567

Comment: Why do you think that SharedPreferences is the problem?  What size is the image?

Comment: size of the image is too small 100kb and moreover i scaled it with BitmapFactory to the size of the display .so the image size should become more small !!

Comment: yes im running it on emulator and on phone . both give the same result

Comment: a) Show your error log that shows exactly why your application is crashing. b) Out of memory errors are mostly when dealing with images.

Comment: The file size is irrelevant.  What size is the image?

Comment: log just says memory out of bound exception

Comment: okay image is very big 1608 X 2504 pixels

Answer (score 0):

Android hardware must at least support 2048x2048.

For OpenGL I used:

```
int[] maxSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
```

- For Nexus 4 it equals to `4096`
- For Sansung 2 it equals to `4096`

You can calculate `[(Height in pixels) x (length in pixels) x (bit depth)] / 8 / 1024 = image size in kilobytes (KB)`

So be sure that you have proper image size.

Hope it will help,